# Android in-app billing (buy me a beer)

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I'm a little confused as my native language is not English. 
However, in documentation of in-app billing for android is written that it can be used for only to buy goods within the application.. no physical goods.

But what about supporting developer, aka "buy me a beer" button? It seems to me as perfect way to make this supporting functionality via in-app billing, but I am not sure if that's okay with google policy.

So, is it okay to use in-app biling in android for "buy me a beer" button or not?

Thanks for your repsonses and experiences.

Comment: It's basically a donation. Your users are not buying physical goods. In fact, their not buying *anything*, i.e. they get nothing in return.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google Play policies, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer: yes

Long Answer: yes. [You can also sell physical goods if you desire.](http://googlecommerce.blogspot.com/2013/05/fast-and-easy-checkout-for-android-apps.html)

You can accomplish both things with the In App purchase API.